# Sometimes Safari opens with blank/empty tabs with window titles of the previous session

Tags: safari, bug

I don’t dare to quit Safari if I want to keep the tabs opened, because this happens quite often on my MacBook, running OSX 10.8.2 and Safari 6.0.2. Is this a known problem?

It is strange because window titles are still there but I cannot reload the page. So I always have to search for the page title to get back to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug - I've reported it but can't force it to happen. If you find a way to trigger it with great reliability you could report it here or to the source at http://bugreporter.apple.com and it might get squashed sooner when the engineers can see exactly what is failing to cause it.

Comment: I think the problem is when the down-link of your internet connection is broken. I was able to reproduce the bug with the Network Conditioner from the Hardware IO Tools collection by setting only the downlink package loss to 100%. The preference pane is available on developers.apple.com and it requires XCode to be installed. Can you reproduce it too?

Answer (score 1):

This has been happening to me and I think I finally managed to figure it out. When you manually remove from the history log the entry relative to a currently open tab, and close Safari then reopen it, that tab will now show a blank page...

Comment: I just tried to reproduce that but no success (OS X 10.10, Safari 8.0). Did you simply remove the history entries from the current tabs?

Comment: I suspect the problem has to do with a broken internet connection (see my comment above), but I'm not entirely sure.